# PyTorch model to C++

Tags: c++, python-3.x, pytorch, onnx

I have trained the detection algorithm and saved my best model. Now I want to convert my model (pretrained) to C++ and use it in my app. I wanted to know what are the possible ways to convert a pyTorch model to c++?

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

- You can use [`TorchScript`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/jit.html) intermediate representation of a PyTorch model, through tracing and scripting, that can be run in C++ environment. For this, you'll probably have to modify the model itself in order for it to be traced or scripted.
- You can use [`ONNX`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/onnx.html) (Open Neural Network Exchange), through which you can export your model and load it in another C++ framework such as Caffe. It comes with its own implications though.
- The easiest is to try [`Embedding Python`](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/embedding.html), through which you can run your python (pytorch) model in C++ environment. Note that the model will still run in python, but only through C++, so there won't be any speed gains that you might be expecting in C++.

Also, with the release of [torchvision 0.5](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/releases/tag/v0.5.0), all models in torchvision have native support for TorchScript and ONNX.

Comment: Thanks for the information! Do you know is there any way to use CUDA with c++ after converting the PyTorch mode to c++?

Comment: Yes, torchscript support CUDA. You can simply use `model->to(at::kCUDA)` and `input.to(at::kCUDA)`.

Comment: This answer is now outdated, as Caffe2 and PyTorch merged in 1.0.